# How to get entity class properties names from dbContext by table name?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, entity-framework-6

I have dbContext and table name.
I would like to receive all properties names from class that represent that table. Important thing - properies names in class, cause in class some properies are corrected with `Column` attribute to make class consistent with db entity.

```
public class MyTable
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Desc { get; set;}
    [Column("DbProp")]
    public int ClassProp{ get; set;}
}
```

Desired output: `["Id", "Desc", "ClassProp"]`

I can get all table fields names from context metadata, but don't know how to "connect" them with `Column` attribute.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTableColumns(DbContext context, string table)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    var tableType = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
                            .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                            .Single()
                            .BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(s => (!s.MetadataProperties.Contains("Type") || (s.MetadataProperties["Type"].ToString() == "Tables"))
                                                 && string.Equals(s.Table ?? s.Name, table, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    return tableType?.ElementType.Properties.Select(f => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = f.Name,
        Value = f.Name
    });
}
```

Comment: By default all properties map to the table, unless you specify something different in the model. If you use any of those properties in a LINQ query, EF will generate a SQL query with that property. If there's no matching column, you'll get an error at runtime. What are you trying to find?

Comment: I think you would have to use reflection to search the assembly and find the class and get its properties. If you have decorated any entity with table name attribute you would further have to look for that attribute value. Are you familiar with reflection?

Comment: @Crowcoder thx, will try

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there are kinda dynamic saving... so you post a form and it will try to dynamically save your form... this save is like generic... but for it I need to have names of properties

Comment: EF is dynamic. Data binding is dynamic. The only thing that would need reflection is the form itself. Everything else just works. You can use reflection to find your class's properties and inspect the **Display** attribute, not `Column`. `Column` is only needed by EF. `Display` allows you to specify names and descriptions for a property